# {% url %} and jquery

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

My views will give a dictionary of "build_id", and there is another view responbile generating the details of a given build_id. I.e., the second view "build_details" takes in a parameter "build_id".

Because I have at least one ids from the dictionary, I am going to generate a table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> Number </td>
<td> Actions </td>
</tr>
{% for index, value in build_history.items %}
    <tr>
    <td> {{index}} </td>
    <td>
        <select id="action_menu">
        <option value=''>-----</option>
        <option value="build_{{value.build_id}}">Build Details</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Each row should have a select box. When I select `Build Details` I should be redirected to a different page.

My Jquery attempt:

```
function onSelectChange(){
    var select = $("#action_menu option:selected");
    if(!(select.val() == ""))
        var build_id = select.val().replace('build_','');
        window.location.href="{% url build_details build_id %}";
}
</script>
```

The problem error is:

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'build_details'
>   with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

I believe this mean build_id was not rendered properly... because we are not dynamically building up the build_id on the JS side (browser side..).

What can I do?  I know I can use hardcode http://mydomain and concaented build_id - this will work. But can I take advantage of template tags? How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

---

**Final Working Code**

Assuming I have a variable contains the length of the dictionary, when we have mutliple `<select>` with the same name, server treats it as if it was one entity. Therefore, we can use name a class, and give each `<select>` (each row has one) an unique numeric ID.

```
# Javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    urlMap = {
    {% for index, value in build_history.items %}
        '{{ value.build_id }}' : '{% url build_details value.build_id %}'{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    };

    $(function() {
        var item_len = parseInt({{dict_len}});
        for (var i = 0; i < item_len; i++){
            $("#"+i.toString()+".action").change(function() {
                  if($(this).val() != '')
                     window.location.href = urlMap[$(this).val()];
            }
        )
    }});
</script>
```

> 

```
# HTML (this is a table, each row has one select)

        <select class="action" id={{index}}>
        <option value=''>-----</option>
        <option value="{{ value.build_id }}">Build Details</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is 100% incompatible with the django template. The django template renders HTML and Javascript, then the javascript runs - at that point, template tags do not even exist.

You'll have to store option value -> URL combinations with django in a javascript array.

```
### Javascript map

urlMap = {
    {% for value in build_history.values %}
        {{ value.build_id }}: '{% url build_details value.build_id %}'
        {% if not forloop.last %},{% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
};

function onSelectChange(){
    var select = $("#action_menu option:selected");
    if(!(select.val() == ""))
        var build_id = select.val().replace('build_','');
        window.location.href=urlMap[build_id];
}
```

You could use jQuery's `data` function to bind data to an element too:

```
### Jquery data

{% for value in build_history.values %}
    $("#action_menu option[value=build_{{ value.build_id }}]")
             .data('href', '{% url build_details value.build_id %}');
{% endfor %}


function onSelectChange(){
    var select = $("#action_menu option:selected");
    if(!(select.val() == ""))
        window.location.href=select.data('href');
}
```

---

Please copy and pasting this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    urlMap = {
    {% for index, value in build_history.items %}
        '{{ value.build_id }}' : '{% url build_details value.build_id %}'{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    };

    $(function() {
         $("#foo").change(function() {
            window.location.href = urlMap[$(this).val()];
        });
    })
</script>
<select id="foo">
    <option value="">---</option>
    {% for index, value in build_history.items %}
      <option value="{{ value.build_id }}">Build Details</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: I was thinking along that line - keep a JS array. Would JSON be a better choice, from views? Thanks.

Comment: AJAX would work, but I don't think this is the appropriate place for it. There are a number of ways to store data -- I just updated an example mapping build_ids to their urls. Another idea would be using jquery data binding which I will post in a moment.

Comment: Thanks. BUt the redirection gives this url http://previous_page_url/undefined. In fact, $(this).date('href') gives "undefined". What could thsi mean?

Comment: it would be `select.data('href')` - I see you didn't just use `$("#action_menu").change()`. Anyways, you can always use the map!

Comment: Right. I still can't get either working. Previously I could get one of them redirects to undefined. I have mutliple action_menu, is this what's causing problem? Thanks! I just edited my post above.

Comment: I'm going to paste a full working example, just copy and paste it and see if it works. Updating in a moment..

Comment: Yomita Thank you very much. I managed to solve the issue with same <select> name. I posted my final code up there. Thanks!